# Can't change the value of my input when initial value is setup with value = {myValue) (when using formik with table inside)

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a `<table>` inside my `<formik>` element because I want the user to change the value of an object in a list (the list is iterated to generate `<tr>`. When the user clicks on the "update" button, the content of the `<td>` becomes a `<Field>` element with the value of the value of the object field. Here is the code :

```
<Formik
  enableReinitialize={true}
  initialValues={{ label: '' }}
  validate={(values) => {
    const errors = {}

    return errors
  }}
  onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
  }}
>
  <Form>
    <table className="styled-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Label</th>
          <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {tabTypeClient.map((typeClient) =>
          typeClient.id === idTypeClientSelected ? (
            <tr>
              <td key={typeClient.id}>{typeClient.id}</td>
              <td key={typeClient.label}>
                <Field type="text" name="label" value={typeClient.label} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                  Validate
                </button>
                &nbsp;
                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={() => setIdTypeClientSelected(0)}
                >
                  Cancel
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ) : (
            <tr>
              <td key={typeClient.id}>{typeClient.id}</td>
              <td key={typeClient.label}>{typeClient.label}</td>
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => setIdTypeClientSelected(typeClient.id)}
              >
                Update
              </button>
            </tr>
          ),
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

The issue I have here is that I can't change the value of the field. The input value is pre-filled with value = {typeClient.label} but I can't change it. Every time I press a key on the keyboard the value goes back to the initial value (typeClient.label).

I know I should set the initial value with `initialValues = {{ label: ''}}` but in this case, I can't (because it is in a table).

Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

enableReinitialize

and not value =

Here is the fixed code :

```
<Formik

            enableReinitialize

                initialValues = {{ label: typeClientSelected.label}}
  
                validate = {values => {
  
                    const errors = {};
  
                    if (!values.label) 
                    {
                        errors.label = 'Champs obligatoire';
                    } 
  
                    return errors;
  
                }}
  
                onSubmit = { async (values , {setSubmitting}) => 
                {
        
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        
                }}
            >

            <Form>
      
            <table className = "styled-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Libellé</th>
                        <td>Action</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                        {tabTypeClientFiltered.map(typeClient =>(
                            typeClient.id === idTypeClientSelected ? (
                                <tr key = {typeClient.id + "ROW"}>
                                    <td key = {typeClient.id}>{typeClient.id}</td>
                                    <td key = {typeClient.label}><Field type="text" name="label"  /></td>
                                    <td key = {typeClient.id + "BUTTONS"}>
                                        <button type="submit" className = "btn btn-primary" >Valider</button>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <button className = "btn btn-primary" onClick = {() => {setIdTypeClientSelected(0);}}>Annuler</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>)
                            :
                            (
                                <tr key = {typeClient.id + "ROW"}>
                                    <td key = {typeClient.id}>{typeClient.id}</td>
                                    <td key = {typeClient.label}>{typeClient.label}</td>
                                    <td key = {typeClient.id + "B"}><button className = "btn btn-primary" onClick = {() => 
                                        {
                                           // var typeClientSelected = tabTypeClient.find(item => item.id === idTypeClientSelected);
                                           //alert(JSON.stringify(typeClient));
                                            setTypeClientSelected(typeClient);
                                            setIdTypeClientSelected(typeClient.id);
                                        }
                                    }>Modifier</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                            )
                        )}

                </tbody>
            </table>

            </Form>

            </Formik>
```